# How does on-demand pruning of kernel work in context of Unikernel?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

In Unikernel computing environment, kernel sometimes can be pruned targeting the need of specific user application.

How does this process work? is it manual or can it be automated?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'pruning' of the kernel. To be clear all unikernel implementations don't use linux - they have written their own kernel (whether they want to admit to that or not).

There are well over 10 different unikernel implementations out there today and some are very focused on providing the absolute bare minimum of things to work. Others, such as [nanos](https://github.com/nanovms/nanos) of which I work on are in the 'posix' category meaning if it runs on linux it'll probably run on here.

Whenever you see references to people talking about 'only including what you need' and picking certain libraries to use -- most of these systems are not much more than a hello world -- which is simple enough to do in ~20 lines of assembly. When you start trying to run real world applications, especially ones that you use everyday (did you write your own database? did you write your own webserver?) and compare things like performance you start running into actual operating system components that you can't just pick/choose.

Having said that, supporting the set of syscalls that linux has is only a portion of the battle. There is a lot of code that goes into a general purpose operating system like linux (north of 20M loc and that's a 'small' kernel) or windows or macos that is not readily recognizable by it's end users. The easy things to point at are picking which network driver to use depending on which hypervisor you want to run it on (xen/kvm/hyper-v).

The harder, less clear things are making choices between things like apic or x2apic? How many levels are your page tables? Do you support smp or not? If so how?

You can't just 'prune' this type of stuff away. It needs to be consciously added and even if you did have a linux that you were 'unikernelizing' you wouldn't be able to prune it cause it just touches too much code. As a thought exercise try removing support for multiple processes (no unikernel supports this). Now you are touching multiple schedulers, shared memory, message passing, user privileges, (are there users?), etc. (this list goes on forever).

Your question is actually a very common question and it highlights a misunderstanding of how these things work in real life.

So to answer your question - there is no work that I'm aware of where people are trying to automatically 'prune' the kernel and even the projects that exist where you can select what type of functionality via config file or something is not something that I would expect to see much progress in because of the aforementioned reasons.